# Get a cell from the address

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA, I would like to do this:

```
Dim cellAddress As String, cell As Range
Set cellAddress = "=Sheet1!A7"
Set cell = GetCellFromAddress(cellAddress)
```

How could I implement "GetCellFromAddress" in the best way? I know I could parse the cellAddress, but that seems a little awkward...

I am using Excel 2007, if it matters.

Comment: Looks to me you want to re-write the range function ? I really don't see the point.

Answer (score 5):

```
Dim cellAddress As String, cell As Range
cellAddress = "=Sheet1!A7"

Set cell = Range(cellAddress)

MsgBox cell.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
```

This will show a messagebox with text:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Excel
---------------------------
[Book1]Sheet1!R7C1
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I think freerider's answer is good enough and I upvoted it.

If you want to see his solution implemented as GetCellFromAddress

```
Function GetCellFromAddress(cellAddress As String) As Range
    Set GetCellFromAddress = Range(cellAddress)
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim cellAddress As String, cell As Range
    cellAddress = "=Sheet1!A7"

    Set cell = GetCellFromAddress(cellAddress)
    MsgBox cell.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
End Sub
```